# What's the point of _mm_cmpgt_sd and other similar methods?

Tags: x86, sse, simd, intrinsics

I was looking for a SIMD option to speed up comparisons and I found the function `__m128d _mm_cmpgt_sd (__m128d a, __m128d b)`

Apparently it compares the lower double, and copies the higher double from `a` into the output. What it is doing makes sense, but what's the point? What problem is this trying to solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point is probably that on very old hardware, such as, e.g., Intel Pentium II and III, `_mm_cmpgt_sd()` is faster than `_mm_cmpgt_pd()`. See Agner Fog's [instruction tables](https://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf). These processors (PII and PIII) only have a 64-bit wide floating point unit. 128-bit wide SSE instructions are executed as two 64-bit micro-ops on these processors. On newer CPUs (such as for example intel Core 2 (Merom) and newer) the `_pd` and `_ps` versions are as fast as the `_sd` and `_ss` versions. So, you might prefer the `_sd` and `_ss` versions if you only have to compare a single element and don't care about the upper 64 bits of the result.

Moreover, `_mm_cmpgt_pd()` may raise a spurious floating point exception or suffer from degraded performance, if the upper garbage bits contain accidently a `NaN` or a subnormal number, see [Peter Cordes’ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55718764/2439725). Although, in practice, it should be easy to avoid such upper garbage bits when programming with intrinsics.

If you want to vectorize your code, and need a packed double compare, then use intrinsic `_mm_cmpgt_pd()`, instead of `_mm_cmpgt_sd()`.

Comment: IIRC, `cmppd` can take an FP assist if garbage in the upper element represents a subnormal `double`.  And some code wants to avoid spurious FP exceptions for comparing possible NaNs.

Comment: But if you don't care about the upper bits, then why not just use a regular old compare operator on a normal data type (e.g. int, double, etc.)? Because you have already loaded some data (for whatever reason) into a wide register? I would think if you only wanted one compare, the higher destination bits would retain their current value, rather than copying the bits from `a`.

Comment: @Jimbo: Actually the highest destination bits do retain their current value, they are unmodified. See page 750 of [Intel's SDM](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/39/c5/325462-sdm-vol-1-2abcd-3abcd.pdf): CMPSD (128-bit Legacy SSE version) ....`DEST[MAXVL-1:64] (Unmodified)`

Comment: @Jimbo: Note that compilers may generate `cmpgtsd` or `cmpltsd` instructions even for a 'regular old compare operator on a normal double data type'. See this [Godbolt link](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/OGcfSB). Because the `cmpltsd` instruction exists, it is natural that `_mm_cmpgt_sd` exists too. Moreover, SIMD code often contains small pieces of non-vectorizable scalar code. In that case it is convenient to have `_mm_cmpgt_sd`, and `_mm_add_sd` etc. Peter Cordes already mentioned `addsd` (`_mm_add_sd`) as the last step of a horizontal sum.

Comment: @wim Point noted regarding the Intel SDM. Now if you ever wanted a large pdf for testing performance, there's one! The information in that document seems to contradict my understanding of the pseudocode on Intel's Intrinsics Guide webpage. Unmodified bits rather than copying from `a` makes these functions make a lot more sense ....

Answer (score 3):

`cmpsd` is an instruction that exists in asm and operates on XMM registers, so **it would be inconsistent *not* to expose it via intrinsics.**

(Almost all packed-FP instructions (other than shuffles/blends) have a scalar version, so again there's a consistency argument for ISA design; it's just an extra prefix to the same opcode, and might require more transistors to special-case that opcode *not* supporting a scalar version.)

**Whether or not you or the people designing the intrinsics API could think of a reasonable use-case is not at all the point.**  It would be foolish to leave things out on that basis; when someone comes up with a use-case they'll have to use inline asm or write C that compiles to more instructions.

Perhaps someone someday will find a use-case for a vector with a mask as the low half, and a still-valid `double` in the high half.  e.g. **maybe `_mm_and_ps` back onto the input to conditionally zero just the low element** without needing a packed-compare in the high element to produce true.

Or consider that all-ones is a bit-pattern for NaN, and all-zero is the bit-pattern for `+0.0`.

---

IIRC, `cmppd` slows down if any of the elements are subnormal (if you don't have the DAZ bit set in MXCSR).  At least on some older CPUs that existed when the ISA was being designed.  So for FP compares, having scalar versions is (or was) essential for avoiding spurious FP assists for elements you don't care about.

**Also for avoiding spurious FP exceptions** (or setting exception flags if they're masked), like if there's a NaN in the upper element of either vector.

@wim also makes a good point that Intel CPUs before Core2 decoded 128-bit SIMD instructions to 2 uops, one for each 64-bit half.  So using `cmppd` when you don't need the high half result would always be slower, even if it can't fault.  Lots of multi-uop instructions can easily bottleneck the front-end decoders on CPUs without a uop-cache, because only one of the decoders can handle them.

---

You don't normally use intrinsics for FP scalar instructions like `cmpsd` or `addsd`, but they exist in case you want them (e.g. as the last step in a horizontal sum).  More often you just leave it to the compiler to use scalar versions of instructions when compiling scalar code without auto-vectorization.

And often for scalar compares, compilers will want the result in EFLAGS so will use `ucomisd` instead of creating a compare mask, but for branchless code a mask is often useful, e.g. for `a < b ? c : 0.0` with `cmpsd` and `andpd`.  (Or really `andps` because it's shorter and does the same thing as the pointless `andpd`.)

Comment: Good points on subnormals and FP exceptions. Note that on modern CPUs there is probably no slowdown in case of subnormal inputs. According to [Agner Fog](https://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf) some of these penalties have been removed since Sandy Bridge. There is no penalty for adding a normal and a subnormal number (page 131) on Sandy Bridge. I did a few simple experiments, but couldn't find any penalty for `cmpsd` either on Skylake.